# CSS Text centering with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, text, centering

I am currently working on a website and for the page titles / post titles i have a div to set color and some text in the center. It works fine on Chrome and Other Browsers but my text isn't centered vertically on IE.

[image: Website on IE]

[image: Chrome]

As you can see in the top image (IE) the text isn't entered vertically, where in chrome it is.

My CSS Code

```css
h1 {
    font: 100% Coolvetica, Tahoma;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    left: 4%;
    width: 91.2%;
    height: 0%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 4;
}
#title {
    font: 100%;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    background: #161616;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 3.7em;
    height: 3.5%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 13px 59px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 13px 59px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 13px 59px #000000;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

My HTML Code

```
<div id="title">
<h1>
Hello Welcome to Our Online Shop!!!
</h1>
</div>
```

Hopefully that is enough information

Thanks Matt

Answer (score 2):

I removed position:absolute for the H1 tag and it works fine in IE.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

h1{ 
font: 100% Coolvetica, Tahoma; 
font-size:2.2em; 
text-align:left; 
/*position:absolute;*/ 
padding-top: auto; 
margin-top: auto;  
margin-bottom: auto;  
left: 4%; 
width: 91.2%; 
height: 0%; 
color: #FFFFFF; 
z-index:4; 
} 

#title{ 
font: 100%; 
font-size:1em; 
text-align:left; 
position:absolute; 
left: 0%; 
background:#161616; 
width: 100%; 
min-height:3.7em; 
height:3.5%;
padding-top:0%; 
margin-bottom:5%; 
margin-top:0%; 
color: #FFFFFF; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 13px 59px #000000; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 13px 59px #000000; 
box-shadow: 0px 13px 59px #000000; 
z-index:5; 
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="title"> 
<h1> 
Hello Welcome to Our Online Shop!!! 
</h1> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still didn't work when i tried it on mine. Might have something to do with the content div. Thankyou for trying :D

Answer (score 2):

You can set specific padding that will be rendered only by IE by putting a star before the style.

```
*padding: 1em;
```

Play with that-- it might help.

Comment: This asterisk hack will only apply to IE 7 and below, not IE8+. However, using any IE CSS hacks is generally not recommended, as much of them rely on invalid CSS.

Comment: If you don't want to use that, then you can use class queries in markup.

<!--[if IE 7 ]><html xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="ie7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><![endif]-->

And so on, and all you have to do is to set the class before the selector to define it, such as:

.ie7 h1 { }

Answer (score 1):

You can try css style attribute `vertical-align:middle;` for title div

Comment: `vertical-align:middle` only applies to inline elements. But even if `div.title` were inline, it would only align `h1` with the so-called _x-height_. In brief, `vertical-align:middle` almost never does what you'd expect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

First off, on Mac OSX the text did not appear to be centered in Chrome 19.

See this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/apiqog/24/edit

If you are willing to ditch the percentage heights on `div#title`, you could set the same height to both `div#title` and `h1`, and also give `h1` a line-height of the same amount.

I'm running a Mac so I don't have IE readily accessible, but I've found that setting the height and the line-height to be the same on a given element is a good approach to vertically align text therein, cross-browser.